# Enable sending to / receiving from a JMS topic in Wildfly 17

Tags: java, jboss, jms-topic, wildfly-17

What settings shall be configured in order to be able to send JMS messages to a given topic in Wildfly 17 and receive them via JMS?

After looking in internet I found the following sources:

[Remote JMS Client for Wildfly 8](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/how-to-code-a-remote-jms-client-for-wildfly-8)

[Not able to send message to a Topic configured on WildFly 9](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261668)

[Integrate ActiveMQ with Wildfly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/integrate-activemq-with-wildfly)

However, none of the above mentioned links solved my problem completely

Answer (score 2):

1.) A special Application user shall be created in Wildfly 17 using the command

```
add-user.sh/add-user.cmd
```

which belongs to the group "guests", and on behalf of whom the JMS Message Producer will create JMS messages. Details about how this user shall be created are given here:

[use add-user.sh/add-user.cmd  to create a new user in Wildfly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/how-to-code-a-remote-jms-client-for-wildfly-8)

2.) Wilffly 17 must be started using

```
standalone-full.xml
```

not just

```
   standalone.xml
```

3.) Message Topic shall be created in Wildfly17, where the messages shall be sent to. This shall be possible either by running  the script `jboss-cli.bat / jboss-cli.bat` with the following arguments:

```
jms-topic add --topic-address=AuctionTopic --entries=[#topic/auction", "java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/auction"]
```

or by directly inserting the following entry at line 537 of standalone-full.xml:

```
<jms-topic name="topic/testTopic" entries="java:/jms/topic/auction java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/auction" />
```

just before the existing line:

```
  <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
```

4.) When a message producer that is a component residing inside Wildfly 17 (such as a servlet) does obtain a JMS Connection from WildFly 17, the following code shall be used:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
// Wildfly 17.00:
// this user and password shall be created before the application is deployed
// with the help of add-user.sh. The jmsuser shall be an application user that // belongs to the group guest
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jmsuser");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Password1!");
        javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

        Object obj = ctx.lookup(Constants.JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) obj;
        this.jmsConnection = factory.createConnection();
        obj = ctx.lookup(Constants.JMS_TOPIC_NAME);
        this.topic = (Topic) obj;
```

where

```
Constants.JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "ConnectionFactory";
```

and

```
Constants.JMS_TOPIC_NAME = "java:/jms/topic/auction";
```